# Symfony2 - PHPSESSID is ever set for all user's roles

Tags: symfony, caching, varnish, php

In my application I noticed that the cookie PHPSESSID is always sent, even though the user's role is "ANONYMOUS" or it is not assigned a token. I have searched on the internet without satisfactory results. 
Is there a way to prevent the sending of this cookie, for users not logged in?

Comment: Which version of symfony are you using? Older versions of symfony had a configuration directive `framework.session.auto_start` ... See: [The framework.session.auto_start setting has been removed in Symfony2.1, it will start on demand now.](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/reference/configuration/framework.html). Further please include your `security.yml` configuration. See **[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12580505/1832745)** for another possibility (related to the firewall config) why the session always gets started .