# Symfony2 - How to disable Cookie for PHPSESSION

Tags: php, symfony, session, cookies

I want to disable the cookie generated by a session in Symfony 2.6. I've already tried:

```
ini_set('session.use_cookies', 0);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 0);
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 1);
```

in the app_dev.php.
It works fine for a controller action which only displays a phpinfo()... There is no cookie generated (I only wonder why the ini-value says:)
 `session.use_cookies: On`
But the controller action where I render a form by:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new RegisterType(), $register, array(
    'method' => 'POST'
));
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

and later

```
return $this->render('XYZRegisterBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
...
```

the cookie is created :(

I think the form object is the reason for cookie creation, maybe because of the csrf-token???

Does anybody know how to disable the Cookie to be generated and saved on the client-side. I want to POST only the values of the form to another controller without the need of a cookie or better session.
If necessary i would also be pleased if i could transmit the session-id in the URL.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why would you send the session-ID in the URL? It may generate some security issues!

Comment: Also, this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578653/symfony2-session-auto-start